# C++ template better than a int->unsigned conversion?

Tags: c++

I have two functions like the following

```
template<typename T>
unsigned int myFunction(T myelement)
{

myelement->func();

return 2;
}

void myFunction(unsigned int myelement)
{
}
```

and I'm using the following code

```
myFunction(2);
```

visual studio 2012 is complaining that "int hasn't ->func()". Why isn't it using the unsigned int version?

Comment: I find your code badly written and difficult to read; I won't recommend coding like that, but it is a matter of opinion and taste.

Comment: Short answer: yes, a function template that instantiates with an exact match for the argument is better than a non-template function with a standard conversion. So for example C++ allows the "wildcard" version of `std::pow` to be a template (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow). This wouldn't make sense if the overloads 1-3 were always better matches than the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misreading the error message. The compiler doesn't *use* the function, it is instantiating it to figure out if it is a candidate. You need to disable the instantiation for non-suitable types:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value, unsigned int >::type
myFunction( T myelement )
{
    // ...
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c9fdbbaeb30d11d)

Answer (score 1):

Try coding

```
myFunction(2U);
```

or

```
myFunction((unsigned)2);
```

The literal `2`  is of `int` (not `unsigned int`) type. And `int` is not a class or a type having `->func()`

And perhaps [specialize the template](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html) for `unsigned` instead of defining a `myFunction(unsigned int)`